# WatchOS App Timer Not Firing When Second Timer Declared

Tags: swift, swiftui, watchos

I am writing my first WatchOS app. I have two timers, one to update a text showing UTC time, declared like this:

```
@State private var zuluTimeStr: String = ""
private let timer1 = Timer.publish(every: 1, on: .main, in: .common).autoconnect()
.
.
.

var body: some View {
        Text(text: zuluTimeStr)
            .onReceive(timer1, perform: { _ in
                self.zuluTimeStr = getTimeString()
            })
    }
```

And another to invalidate certain values if they are too old, declared like this:

```
private var timer2: Timer?
.
.
.
timer2 = Timer.scheduledTimer(withTimeInterval: 1, repeats: true, block: { _ in
     self.invalidateOldData()
})
```

First timer is declared in a subview, and second timer is declared in an `ObservableObject` descendant.

However, `timer1` stops firing when `timer2` is scheduled. It seems like I am either limited to one timer in WatchOS, or `timer2` is somehow overriding `timer1`. Any thoughts?

Comment: Why Timer, look at TimelineView

Comment: @loremipsum Because I didn't know that it existed? :D This solved my immediate problem, much appreciated. However, in the interest of understanding why having two timers doesn't work, I'd like to keep the question open.

Comment: It could be any number of things without a complete example I would just be guessing. But they aren’t really necessary and are usually really buggy.